# Get Last day of previous month by using MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

at present, I need to get the last day of previous Month for every month
how can i achieve this by using MDX
i try to use tail function but can not get the data i want.
can you help me with this problem?
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the previous month you can use PrevMember or lag(1) functions and you can do something like:

```
[Date].[Month].currentMember.PrevMember
```

And to get the last day you can use the tail function on the month descendents (which are the days). So depending on your date dimension it will become something like:

```
With Member [Measures].[Last Day Prev Month] As
Tail(DESCENDANTS( [Date].[Month].currentMember.PrevMember ).Item(0).Member_caption
```

P.S. I don't have ssas installed currently so I cannot test it but the idea is valid ;)